# PayPal API request for SetExpressCheckout failed in Kohana 3.2 (PHP 5.3)

Tags: php, paypal, kohana

we have used Kohana 3.2 (PHP 5.3). Paypal now not working we got below the error message.

```
PayPal API request for SetExpressCheckout failed: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)
```

This is our curl setup

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $this->api_url(),
        CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post, NULL, '&'),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        //CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1',
    ));
```

Comment: Take a look at this post about the [POODLE Vulnerability](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).  That's what you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

The "handshake failure" is related to SSL certificates. Can be helpful to visit www.paypal.com/mts and then look for the document "2016 Merchant Security Roadmap Microsite" which will show all the latest information on this subject and what to do exactly. The microsite expalin very well all the necessary steps to perform.
Andrea